# How to represent this data as a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have data set that looks as follows

DATE--------TIME--------CONSUMPTION

1.1.2014----04:30-------------40

1.1.2014----05:30-------------60

1.1.2014----06:30-------------50

the data spans for 1 year and for every 30 mins every day.
I need to convert this data into time series in R at day level and at month level.
How to achieve this in R.

Answer (score 0):

You should give more data points, since you would like to aggregate to daily or monthly frequency.

Is this what you are after...

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

my_data <-
  c("DATE--------TIME--------CONSUMPTION", "",
    "1.1.2014----04:30-------------40", 
  "", "1.1.2014----05:30-------------60", "", 
  "1.1.2014----06:30-------------50") %>% 
  str_split(., "-")

my_almost_ok_df <-
  lapply(my_data[my_data != ""], 
       function(x){x[x!= ""]}) %>% 
  ldply(.)

my_names <- 
  my_almost_ok_df[1, ] %>% 
  unlist(.) %>% 
  unname(.)

my_ok_df <- 
  my_almost_ok_df[-1, ]

names(my_ok_df) <- my_names

my_result <-
  my_ok_df %>% 
  mutate(DATE = dmy(DATE),
         CONSUMPTION = as.numeric(CONSUMPTION)) %>% 
  group_by(DATE) %>% 
  summarise(CONS_mean = mean(CONSUMPTION),
            CONS_sum = sum(CONSUMPTION))

my_result

        DATE CONS_mean CONS_sum
1 2014-01-01        50      150
```

To get to time series representations just select a column you like and use either ts() or zoo() or xts() time series representation.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to do a bit manipulation on `data.frame` using `aggregate` and the convert it to `ts`

```
x <- data.frame(date = c("1.1.2014","1.2.2014","1.1.2014"), 
                time = c("4:30", "5:30", "6:30"), 
                consumption =c(40,50,60))
x$date <- as.Date(x$date, "%m.%d.%Y")
by.day <- aggregate(x[[3]],list(x[[1]]),sum)
ts.by.day <- ts(by.day)
```

With `by month` it is a bit more tricky. The way I see it is to convert to textual representation and the `aggregate` (continuing code above).

```
x$date <- c("2.1.2014","1.2.2014","1.1.2014")
x$date <- format(x$date, "%m.%Y")
by.month <- aggregate(x[[3]],list(x[[1]]),sum)
ts.by.month <- ts(by.day)
```

Comment: first of all thanks for going through my question, actually this alone is not my data  there are around 50000 data points collected over a year for 24 hrs a day. of all the examples i have seen in the net about time series in R , the row names are year and column names are months. This is where i need help, i need to create a time series where the representation in day as column name and hours of day as row name, and the data points represent the consumption ......please advice.